# Extracting Yelp Rating Review

Tags: python, web-scraping, pycharm

I am very new to web scraping and have recently begun scraping a restaurant on yelp.
I am having trouble extracting users' review ratings and every time I try, there seem to be no matches.

```
rating = review.find('img', attrs={'class': 'offscreen__373c0__1KofL'}).get('alt')
rating_list = re.findall('\d+', rating)

if len(rating_list) > 0:
   rating_float = float(rating_list[0])
   print(rating_float)
else:
   print("No matches have been found")
```

Is my `"review.find('img', attrs={'class': 'offscreen__373c0__1KofL'}).get('alt')"` is wrong?

I've added Selenium as the comments indicated but it is still coming up short.

The Url link:https://www.yelp.com/biz/el-farolito-san-francisco-2?osq=Mexican%20Food

url rating: src="https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/public/stars_v2.yji-52d3d7a328db670d4402843cbddeed89.png"

Any other suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share URL of the restaurant rating? Maybe the ratings are added dynamically via JavaScript and beautifulsoup doesn't see them.

Comment: If inserted by Javascript (as Andrej) said, you can always use Selenium (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)